# How to get HTML DOM inside layout from javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, dom

Can I get the information of DOM's layout after it rendered?
To be specific, I want to know inside a

DOM:
How many lines are there? 
Where is the position of each line?
How many words are there in each line?
Where does each word locate in line?
Where does each word locate in

?

Is it possible for me to get these information from java-script after an HTML pager is rendered?

Thanks

Comment: May be words we can but I don't think we can count lines and number of words in each line as it'll be depend on the browser width and etc.

And I'm just curious to know, why do you need these details.

Comment: Yes, you are right as it should be depend on the browser width and etc. However, after HTML page fitting for this browser, browser must follow something to display it. I am wondering whether we can get that "something".